# How to delete from txt.file RESTful Java

Tags: java

I'm new in Java Language, and I try to make a RESTful service. I have a problem with my DELETE function. I try to save the new arrayList in my file after I delete a value. In my console the value that I want to delete is deleted, but in my file, is still remains.

```
@GET
@Path("/arraylist")
public ArrayList<Student>displayJsonFile() throws IOException{  
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    File jsonFile = new File("/students.txt");
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(jsonFile);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    while (fileInput.hasNextLine()){    
        String jsonLine = fileInput.nextLine();

        Student singleStudent = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Student.class);
        students.add(singleStudent);
    }
    fileInput.close();
    return students;    
}



@DELETE
@Path("/delUser/{id}/{name}/{yearOfBirth}") 

    public String delStudents(@PathParam("id") String id, @PathParam("name") String name,@PathParam("yearOfBirth") int yearOfBirth) throws IOException{ 

        Student delStudent = new Student();
        delStudent.setId(id);
        delStudent.setName(name);
        delStudent.setYearOfBirth(yearOfBirth);

        ArrayList<Student> studentss = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for(int j = 0 ; j<displayJsonFile().size(); j++){

            studentss.add(j, displayJsonFile().get(j)) ;

        }

        for(int i=0;i<displayJsonFile().size();i++){

            if(studentss.get(i).equals(delStudent)){
                studentss.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        return "Student deleted !";

    }
```

Comment: Have you considered maybe saving the data back to the file?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any code in your DELETE method to remove the student from the file.

This code snippet should do it.

```
@DELETE
@Path("/delUser/{id}/{name}/{yearOfBirth}") 

    public String delStudents(@PathParam("id") String id, @PathParam("name") String name,@PathParam("yearOfBirth") int yearOfBirth) throws IOException{ 

        Student delStudent = new Student();
        delStudent.setId(id);
        delStudent.setName(name);
        delStudent.setYearOfBirth(yearOfBirth);

        ArrayList<Student> studentss = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for(int j = 0 ; j<displayJsonFile().size(); j++){

            studentss.add(j, displayJsonFile().get(j)) ;

        }
        for(int i=0;i<displayJsonFile().size();i++){

            if(studentss.get(i).equals(delStudent)){
                studentss.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        File oldJsonFile = new File("/students.txt");
        oldJsonFile.delete();
        File jsonFile = new File("/students.txt"); 
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fnew, false);   
        for (Student student : studentss) {
             // Add a public String toJsonString method to your student 
             // class to convert your Student object to json
             // or use Gson's serializer and call it here to generate json
             fw.write(student.toJsonString());
        }
        fw.close();
        return "Student deleted !";

    }
```

Comment: There is no `foreach` in the java language!

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was very useful. I want to ask you another thing, if you don't mind.  How can I make my file path, an universal path, because I use the entire path, for example:  C:/Users/Lucky/workspace/App/WebContent/students.txt, and I have issues when I run on another pc. First I try: this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/students.txt"); and second this method:  this.getClass().getResource( "/students.txt" ).getPath(). , but without any success. Thanks.